# Issues with Swig when I want to extend a given class with Swig %extend

Tags: c++, python, wrapper, swig

I have this following code in my Swig file (.i) :

```
%extend vgSofa::handler::VertexShape
{

        vgd::Shp< vgSofa::handler::VertexShape > createVSWithNode( sofa::simulation::Node * root )
        {
            vgd::Shp< vgSofa::handler::VertexShape > result( new vgSofa::handler::VertexShape() );

            return result->init(root) ? result : vgd::Shp< vgSofa::handler::VertexShape >();
        }           

        vgd::Shp< vgSofa::handler::VertexShape > createVSWithBsicHandler( vgd::Shp<vgSofa::handler::BasicHandler> h )
        {
            return vgSofa_handler_VertexShape_createVSWithNode( $self, h->getRoot() );
        }   


};
```

in .cpp file created, swig adds another parameter in my methods :

```
SWIGINTERN vgd::Shp< vgSofa::handler::VertexShape > vgSofa_handler_VertexShape_createVSWithBsicHandler(vgSofa::handler::VertexShape *self,vgd::Shp< vgSofa::handler::BasicHandler > h)
{...}
```

How do I prevent the addition of this additional parameter to VertexShape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a normal behavior. SWIG's `%extend` directive generates stand-alone functions in the generated code. If you use `$self` in the body, that function is provided with an argument (named "self") that is a pointer to an instance of the C++ class.

As a side note: C++ does the same thing under the hood. The `this` pointer is implicitly passed as first argument to all non-static member functions.

Comment: Thank you,as you said the parameter $self is added in all non-static function parameters, I've declared my function as static and the problem has been solved.